# Too loud shutter sound/mirror slap on Canon 1100D, is it just me?

Tags: shutter, mirror, canon-1100d

My Canon 1100D is loudest of the all DSLRs in my friends group. I want to know if this is a problem with my camera or all 1100Ds are like this.

I have tested it as following:

1. Tried different lenses. With any lens, it makes really loud noise. I know it is not the sound of lens aperture blades snapping back in place as I have tried it with manual lenses.
2. Tried shooting with live view. The noise is less.
3. Tried without attaching a lens. I can see the mirror slap at top of the frame really hard. There is a cushion like sponge there but it hardly makes any difference.

I know this has been discussed before in [Can anything be done to reduce the shutter sound on my SLR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3301/can-anything-be-done-to-reduce-the-shutter-sound-on-my-slr), **so my question is mainly to people who have used Canon 1100D /Rebel T3.** Is it louder for you? If it is not, should I take my camera to service center as I am worried about mirror slapping and breaking itself.

*(I have compared sounds with Canon 350D,450D,550D,60D, Nikon D90.. comparing with 60D/D90 was foolishness, made me almost cry :D )*

Comment: If you really want to cry, compare it with a Pentax K-5. :)

Comment: I was at the Peabody Essex Museum many years ago, there was an exhibit of pinhole photography that was taken with cameras made to remind you of the scene. The camera and the shot was displayed. For example, there were pinhole cameras made from gas cans and photos of gas stations taken with those cameras. The best though was the VW Micro bus which was made into a huge format camera. The shutter was the sliding door on the side. Now I can only imagine what sound that made! :- )

Comment: I've heard others complain about the 1100D, so it's probably not just you.

Comment: I have the Rebel XS (1000D I believe) and there's no way I'd ever be able to use that in a sound concious environment such as a wedding. It's ridiculous how loud it is.

Answer (score 10):

I do own a 1100D and don't find the mirror noise so loud. In Live View, the mirror is up, so that would explain the lower noise when you take the picture. My advice would be to go to a shop and compare the noise with the 1100D that is on display. IF it is the same, then your ears may just be too sensitive. If it isn't, then head out to the service center and have an authorized repair shop to look at it...

EDIT: Since then, there's been a video ([here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4TKj-kJ2QM)) going around the web showing all Canon EOS shutter sounds in Burst mode, including the EOS 1100D. It may help you as a reference...

Answer (score 0):

I find the Canon 6500D very loud too. Makes me very self conscious in quiet environments - and wouldn't dare to use in certain performances!

Comment: 6500D? Are you sure you don't mean the 650D?